# How to hide a complete DataGrid row?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataGrid, from which I add and remove items. This is the code I currently have:

```
  <DataGrid x:Name="ItemsToDo">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Info>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDone}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Deadline">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDone}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding InputDeadline}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

but when both columns of a row are set to collapsed, the row doesn't disappear, but it looks like this:
Entry 2 isn't completely gone

[image]

How do I remove this row without using the view model? Is there a better property than visibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the `DataTrigger`s from your cells' templates and apply the visibility trigger on the whole row, not on individual cells.

For example:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDone}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Info">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Deadline">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding InputDeadline}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```